# What Listener we can use, after get date from DB in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, listener

In Hibernate 4.0.1.Fianl,

After **Insert data** to DB, we can call  ---->   PostInsertEventListener ----override method---------> onPostInsert
After **Delete data** from DB, we can call ----> PostDeleteEventListener ----override method-----> onPostDelete
After **Update data** to DB, we can call ----> PostUpdateEventListener ----override method------> onPostUpdate

Like that only, what listener we can use get data from DB?

After **Get data** from DB, we can use ---------> ???? (what listener in Hibernate)

Please any one help me...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `LoadEventListener` implementation that extends the hibernate `DefaultLoadEventListener`:

```
   // this is the single method defined by the LoadEventListener interface
public void onLoad(LoadEvent event, LoadEventListener.LoadType loadType) 
        throws HibernateException {
        super.onLoad(event, loadType);

        //do something post load
    }
}
```

`super.onLoad()` handles default loading and **after** you can do your stuff.

See also the [hibernate docs related to the event system](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/manual/en-US/html_single/#objectstate-events) and [how to register custom events listeners in the hibernate dev guide](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch07.html#integrators).

Comment: When i use this override method, I got "Object type change to void type". what I do dcernahoschi?

Comment: Updated the answer. In hibernate 4 onLoad doesn't return anything.

Comment: This LoadEventListener case couldn't work, after get data from Database. Please tell any other way to solve this problem.

Comment: Following method am used, public void onLoad(LoadEvent event, LoadEventListener.LoadType loadType) 
         throws HibernateException
    {
  System.out.println("---------load Instance listener------------>> "+event.getInstanceToLoad());
     
    }             This is correct or not. After get data from DB, this print statement not print. Give any other way.

Comment: You need to register the custom event listener. Take a look at the documentation links provided.

Comment: How can I register "EventType.EVICT", ownListener in Hibernate?